esvect.sty error - tex4ht
I'm using:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \vv{V_P}=\vv{V}_{C_{R}}+r \vv{k} \times \vv{C_{RP}}
\label{eq:kin1}
\end{align}

\begin{align}\label{eq:kin4}
\begin{matrix}
\vv{V_P}=r {k} \times ({C_KP}-d {i})= r {k} \times {C_{KP}} -d r{j} \\
   = {V_{P,kin}}+  {V_{P,dyn}}\\
   \end{matrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}

when running make4ht, it produced error as Only one # is allowed per tab, also the above arrow as treated as image not the mathml code, how can I fix this? Please suggest

For the MathML output, you can use this esvect.4ht file:
\def\:tempa#1{%
  \bgroup\HCode{<mover><mrow>}#1\HCode{</mrow><mo>&rarr;</mo></mover>}\egroup
}

\HLet\ESV@vecteur\:tempa
\def\:tempa#1#2{%
  \ESV@vecteur{{#1}\sb{#2}}
}
\HLet\vvstar\:tempa

\Hinput{esvect}

It will need some more polishing before I can add it to TeX4ht sources, most notably, it doesn't work with the default LaTeX math. But it should be OK for your use case. This is the result:


Thanks, will check it and get back

It's working like a champ, thanks a ton
